# push is not working on the controller which was presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Hello I have a button on FirstViewController and I dragged a segue from firstViewController to secondViewController as segue Modally. Now on the secondViewController I am generating a Button Programmatically and to go on the third controller I am pushing the controller(segue Push) But its not working. thirdcontroller doesn't comes up. Nothing happening when I click the custom button.

Here is the secondViewController code

```
 func nextButtonClicked(sender:UIButton!){
    let takeProductPhotoController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("takeProductPhotoController") as! TakeProductPhotoController
            takeProductPhotoController.trip = trip
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(takeProductPhotoController, animated: true)
}
```

Note: I don't need the NavigationBar on Second View Controller so while presenting it modally it didn't show the navigationBar. But I need the navigationBar on the third one.  So thats why I am pushing in naviagtioncontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Whenever you want push from the popped controller you have to creat
  the new `NavigationController` & also set the `ViewController` which you
  want to present modaly as `rootViewController` of `navigationController`.
- When we want to present the `SecondViewcontroller`modally, We are presenting 
  navigation controller with `rootViewController` set to `SecondViewController`. So we
  have created the new navigation stack. After that we are going to
  push the controller in the new navigation stack created while presenting `SecondViewController`.

1) Your code should be look like this
in `FirstViewController`

```
let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("aIdentifier") as! SecondViewController 
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondViewController )
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

2) From `secondViewController` you can push `ThirdViewController` in
   `self.naviagtionController`.
Write below code in SecondViewController on Button Action

```
let thirdViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cIdentifier") as! ThirdViewController self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdViewController , animated: true)}
```

Comment: okay you mean I have to write this code.. 

 let nav : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("takeProductPhotoController") as! TakeProductPhotoController) 
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean,but present navigation controller instead of push@ hellowsheikh

Comment: could you provide me the exact syntax since I am struggling to make it work.. I have tried this 

  var rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController as UINavigationController
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var takeProductPhotoController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("takeProductPhotoController") as! TakeProductPhotoController
            rootViewController.pushToViewController(takeProductPhotoController, animated: true)
problem is self.window is not available in this VC so getting syntax error

Comment: okay Thanks for your code its working but the controller is popping up from the bottom like modally controller pops up. I want controller comes up like push segue'

Comment: secondViewController  will be pop from bottom & if you push controller over second controller it will show as push

Comment: well yes I did that when I write this line   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated:true)

next controller doesn't comes up 

and if I use this line self.presentViewController(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
the next controller comes up but from the bottom like modally ?

Comment: You want your ThirdViewController to be pushed.So when you are on SecondVC  say like this    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated:true)

Comment: okay I tried this. still nothing comes up when I click the button.

Comment: oh hangon.. I think I am missing something

Comment: can we discuss this in stackoverflow in chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103364/discussion-between-rohit-kp-and-hellosheikh).

Answer (score 1):

okay I am posting in detail here what was I doing and what I did to solve my problem in which Rohit Answer helped me.

My `FirstVC` was connected to `SecondVC` via segue as `presentModally` in IB. and then In **SecondVC** when I tried to push the `ThirdVC`

```
let thirdVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdVC") as! ThirdVC

  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
```

It didn't work.

So to solve this I deleted the `segue` from IB which was between **FirstVC** and **SecondVC** and wrote this code in my **firstVC**

```
let secondVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondVC") as! SecondVC
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController )
        self.presentViewController(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

and then in **secondVC**

```
let thirdVC =   self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdVC") as! ThirdVC

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
```

IT works

Comment: remember in swift 4 `presentViewController ` is renamed to `present`